# How can I authorize actions by roles (using Can Can or alternative) in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

I have some pages, for example, and Index of all Users, that I only want accessible if User.role == "admin".

It looks like can can lets me define whether someone can manage or read at the Model level, but I want to differentiate capabilities at specific actions in the controller.

How do I do that?

Comment: If you are asking what I think you are then maybe you should check out this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)